# Validation when "adding products" in the admin

Tags: magento

I'm  sure this is simple, but haven't been able to find an answer. I have several custom attributes on on a Simple product in magento and I need to validate that if one option is set, the other is required.

Example if they choose "shirt" from a drop down they must fill in the size.

Thanks,
Blake

Answer (score 2):

If you want further options to be dependent on previous selections, you really need to make this as a configurable product.

For example if you have T Shirts in Blue, Red & Green. There are only Medium & Large sizes in Blue.

When the user chooses the size blue, the next dropdown will be enabled and only the sizes Medium and Large will be available.

It sounds like you need a similar solution.

Comment: I think its more than just a variant the example I gave was bad. Lets say that the I have field called "Forms Type" that is a drop down. If the choose the type type "legal" I need to validate that they also entered information in another text box called "Form Groups". Somehow I think I need to override the save functionality. Ill take a closer look at configurable products though thankyou!